# How does partitioning of DStreams ( for updateStateByKey() ) work and how to verify it?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using `updateStateByKey()` operation to maintain state in my Spark Streaming application. The input data is coming through a Kafka topic.

1. I want to understand how are DStreams partitioned?
2. How does the partitioning work with mapWithState() or updateStatebyKey() method?
3. In updateStateByKey() does the old state and the new values against a given key processed on same node ?
4. How frequent is the shuffle for updateStateByKey() method ?

The state I have to maintaining contains ~ 100000 keys and I want to avoid shuffle every time I update the state , any tips to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Link to the answer to the same question by Tathagat Das :

https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg43512.html

Following is the text :

Both `mapWithState()` and `updateStateByKey()` by default uses the `HashPartitioner`, and hashes the key in the key-value `DStream` on which the state operation is applied. The new data and state is partition in the exact same partitioner, so that same keys from the new data (from the input `DStream`) get shuffled and colocated with the already partitioned state RDDs. So the new data is brought to the corresponding old state in the same machine and then the
state mapping /updating function is applied.

The state is not shuffled every time, only the batches of new data is shuffled in every batch

Comment: Understanding something and being able to explain that are two very different things. The above reads like mumbo jumbo to me. :( Some statements are not even valid English.

Answer (score 0):

updateStateByKey takes a Partitioner as it's second argument. http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions

Comment: I don't think this fully answers the question - can you add some more details?